# Loading more data from database while database is getting new data every minute

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my frontend, which is built with angular 6, I have a gallery page that shows the top results with filters and search bar and all that. The entries that need to be shown in the gallery page are loaded from my dotnet core web API through linq that talks with the SQL database. I'm thinking about loading 10 top entries first and use a 'load more' button to get the next 10 entries by skipping the number of entries I already have displayed. From what I'm predicting the user could experience a small bug, that I don't know how to fix:

If the database was updated in the meantime, the user could see double entries because one new entry could cause the database to generate the list differently. The new entry could come in at position 10 and push an entry that was previously on position 10 to position 11 making it appear on position 10 and 11 on the frontend.

How can I fix this problem based on this logic?

Comment: The easiest way is if you accept that sometimes fewer than 10 items may be added when the user clicks "load more".  Simply compare the Ids of the new items to the Ids of items already displayed, and discard any that are already in the list.

You should ensure that the method you use to order the items in your SQL query is deterministic to minimise chances of this happening.

Comment: Generally as long as your data increments a primary key, a "load more" button should just select data with incremented key values. Also, if the first set of results have changed, check for those and update accordingly.